# Intercept android share intent choice to provide different content

Tags: android, social-networking

I want to offer users the chance to share an image to their social channel of choice. I don't want to integrate a bunch of different SDKs because urgh too much work and anyway people like snapchat don't provide an sdk.

So great, let's use android's share intent and just let the user choose! However different services have different requirements for photos. Twitter prefers 2:1 aspect ratio pictures, and instagram prefers square. I have to make too many compromises to the image to make one image that looks good on both.

On iOS I can intercept the share destination from a UIActivityViewController and substitute in a different image. Is there a similar way to do this on android? Or once the intent has been sent, is that it?

Comment: Create the basic `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` with the proper MIME type for your image format. Use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to see who handles that. Provide your own UI for letting the user choose what to share with. Use their selection to create an explicit edition of your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` (i.e., with the `ComponentName` attached) and `EXTRA_STREAM` set to whatever `Uri` you want. Your `Uri` would point to an image that you deem to be suitable, either because you recognize the choice and use an image designed for it, or some base image to use for everything else.

Comment: Beat me to it.  I've done something like this before.  And although some services do not provide SDKs, most do provide image resources so you can potentially show appropriate logos for the most common options.   I check for and display a handful of specific share options if I detect the apps are installed...along with a final choice of "other" that simply triggers the normal share intent which can pick up less popular apps.